# Android P is blocking Camera access

Tags: android, service, background, android-camera, android-camera2

I have implemented an application which captures image in background(Broadcast Event) and it is working in all devices,

As per google's [policy](https://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes) for android P, I can not use it in background,

Does anyone have any solution for this?

Comment: Have you tried running a foreground service?

Comment: I am capturing image from camera on Broadcast event, foreground service wont work for me